# document.getElementById("id").action on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I use the `.action` attribute to set a `CKEDITOR` instante on an `AJAX` response:

```
document.getElementById("ID").action=CKEDITOR.replace('text_area_ID', {
    //settings
});
```

Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

Comment: You mean `.prop`? http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Yes, but there's no real benefit to doing it with jQuery instead.

Comment: why -2? Isn't this site to ask question? This seems to be a question to me...

Comment: The question is clear.  It might help a few people see how jQuery simplifies Javascript.  But it does lack research effort.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#ID')[0].action = CKEDITOR.replace('text_area_ID', {
    //settings
});
```

Alternatively, you may use the [jQuery Adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) provided by CKEditor:

```
$('#ID').ckeditor({
    // settings
});
```

Comment: How much more non-redundant jQuery can I add here?

Comment: `$('#id').prop('action', ...);` for instance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but unless the element selected is a `form`, there is no action property. I've also updated my answer to accommodate another method.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a form, otherwise the whole thing is pretty pointless. Nice touch on the adapter :)